# Difficulties creating a scatter graph in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 4 columns of data to display in a scatter graph in excel

Trade Name
Amatib 
AMOXICI
Amoxinsol
Amoxival 
Amoxy Activ
Bioamoxi 
Biocillin 
Citramox 
CITRAMOX 50
MAXYL 
Octacillin 
Rhemox
SOLAMOCTA 
Trioxyl500

Irl DDD
16
15
15
20
20
20
15
15
15
15
12
15
13.1
15

AVE Irl 
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8
15.8

EU DDD
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16

I want the y axis to be a list of the names in a row and the x axis to go somewhere from 10 to 22 with each number a non connected point, or just the first two rows of data and then I can add in a straight line for the 15.8 and 16. I can't figure out how to do it!

Thanks

Comment: lbr - did this below solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

lbr, you will have to use a **Line Chart** and then make it look like a scatter. Scatter seems to only accept numeric x and y axis values.

[image: scatter as line chart]

Here I selected my Trade Name and irlDD data in columns and went Insert Line Chart. Then I set:
Line - No Line
Marker Options - built in

Let me know if you need more help with this. To set the axis to 10 to 22 then you will just format the y axis (double click on axis, set the minimum bound to 10 for example).